# iPhone sync failing without error

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup

So I have the latest version of iTunes on my PC, 12.10.4. I also have the latest iOS version on my iPhone 7, which is 13.3.1.

I don't know if this is related but I will mention it anyway. I just uninstalled the Windows Store iTunes and downloaded+setup the apple.com download of iTunes.

The problem is that when I plug in my phone to the computer, it shows up like normal, but it only shows 'Other' as the largest type of data. So I go ahead and select automatic backup on computer.

When I press "Sync" the "Syncing [phone] (Step 1 of 4)" message shows up at the top like normal but then disappears and the entire process stops and nothing happens. No error message shows up. There is no indication that anything even happened. When I go to the home page of iTunes and right click my device, the 'back up' option is disabled. The back up option is also disabled on the back up panel in the iPhone Summary page.
[image: Backup page, option disabled]

What can I do to back up my phone? None of the online options seem to match or solve this problem.

Comment: I'd also like to say that when I select something to sync, like my camera roll, an error shows up saying "This iPhone [name] could not be synced because the connection was lost." Don't know if that helps.